# Can you reference a destructured function parameter in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm going to begin by saying that this is purely a matter of syntax candy-

I have a number of javascript functions with this general signature:

`const someFn = async (context, args) => {}`

Each implementation deconstructs those two objects. For example:

`const myHttpFn = async({req, res}, {id, name, potato}) => { ... }`

Within the implementation, I'd like to be able to deconstruct the object in the signature (this makes it easy for users to see what arguments are truly required) but still have a reference to the rest of the object (some properties are pass-through). The closest I've come has been by wrapping both arguments in an object like so:

```
const { isCold, isDry } = require('./some/utilities');

const lunch({context, context:{fridge, pantry, sandwitchMaker}, {ingredientList, shouldHeat}) => {
  const coldList = ingredientList.filter(isCold);
  const dryList = ingredientList.filter(isDry);
  const [cold, dry] = await Promise.all(
    fridge.fetch(context, { list: coldList }),
    pantry.fetch(context, { list: dryList })
  );
  return sandwitchMaker.cook(context, { cold, dry, shouldHeat });
}

const sandwitch = await lunch({context, { 
  ingredientList: ["bread", "cheese", "tomato", "bacon", "bacon", "lettuce", "mayo"],
  shouldHeat: true
}});
```

Adding the wrapper object gives me access to both `context` as a whole as well as the pieces that I've deconstructed. Is there a way to do this without a wrapper object?

Comment: You can destructure to get specific attributes, or you can have a regular attribute, but I don't think JavaScript supports a catch-all "kwargs" in addition to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without your so-called wrapper object, but you can have just the wrapper object in the function definition - something like

```
const lunch({context: {fridge, pantry, sandwitchMaker, ...other}, {ingredientList, shouldHeat}) => {
    const context = {fridge, pantry, sandwitchMaker, ...other};
    //... rest of your code
}
```